# i have created a mobile chat app using kivy. it works in my pc but not in my phone

Tags: python, sockets, kivy, buildozer

**my problam**

i have created a mobile chat app using kivy and buildozer in google colab. it works in my pc very nice but it doesn't connect to my server using my phone in my local network.

**part of my .spec file **

note: i gave the internet permission in my buildozer.spec file as follow:

```
android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)
```

this is my requirements part

```
requirements = python3,kivy, rsa
```

**my code**

my code is as follow. in which first of all i take the servers ip and a nikname. after connection established i try to invisible the part corresponding to ip and nikname parts. finally user tries to send his messages to other persons.
this app works very well in my pc but it it doesn't connect to my server.

```
import kivy
import socket
import threading
import rsa 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import mainthread

kivy.require('1.9.0')

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
public_key, privet_key= rsa.newkeys(1024)


class MyRoot(BoxLayout):
    server_public_key=None
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()
        
    @mainthread
    def update_chat_text(self, message):
        self.chat_text.text += message + "\n"   

    def send_message(self):
        client.send(rsa.encrypt(f"{self.nickname_text.text}: {self.message_text.text}".encode(), self.server_public_key))

    
    def connect_to_server(self):
        if self.nickname_text.text != "":
            client.connect((self.ip_text.text, 9999))
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if message == "NICK":
                client.send(self.nickname_text.text.encode('utf-8'))
                self.server_public_key=rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(client.recv(1024))
                client.send(public_key.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
                self.send_btn.disabled = False
                self.message_text.disabled = False
                self.connect_btn.disabled = True
                self.ip_text.disabled = True
                self.make_invisible(self.connection_grid)
                self.make_invisible(self.connect_btn)
                thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
                thread.start()

    def make_invisible(self, widget):
        widget.visible = False
        widget.size_hint_x = None
        widget.size_hint_y = None
        widget.height = 0
        widget.width = 0
        widget.text = ""
        widget.opacity = 0

    def receive(self):
        stop = False
        while not stop:
            try:
                message = rsa.decrypt(client.recv(1024), privet_key).decode()
                self.update_chat_text(message)
            except Exception as ex:
                print("ERROR:", ex)
                client.close()
                stop = True

    

class NeuralWebChat(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyRoot()

neuralWebChat = NeuralWebChat()
neuralWebChat.run()
```

**here is my neuralwebchat.kv**

in this section i have provided my .kv file

```
<MyRoot>
        
        
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ip_text: ip_text
    nickname_text: nickname_text
    connection_grid: connection_grid
    connect_btn: connect_btn
    chat_text: chat_text
    send_btn: send_btn
    message_text: message_text
    
    GridLayout:
        id: connection_grid

        rows: 1
        cols: 2

        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        height: 125
        size_hint: (1,None)
        background_color: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: "Server IP"
                font_size: 42
                color: 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1
            #rgb opacity
            TextInput:
                id: ip_text
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: 50
                font_size: 36
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: "Nickname_text"
                font_size: 42
                color: 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1
            TextInput:
                id: nickname_text
                size_hint: (1, None)
                height: 50
                font_size: 36
    
    
    Button:
        id: connect_btn
        text: "Connect"
        font_size: 36
        size: 100, 50
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: 70
        background_color: 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1
        on_press: root.connect_to_server()
    
    Label:
        text: "Chat History"
        font_size: 42
        height: 50
        size_hint: (1, None)
        color: 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1
    
    TextInput:
        id: chat_text
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 350
        size_hint: (1, None)
        font_size: 36
        readonly: True
        disabled: True
        multiline: True
        background_color: 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1
    Label:
        text: "Your Message"
        font_size: 42
        color: 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: 50
    TextInput:
        id: message_text
        font_size: 36
        disabled: True
        size_hint: (1, None)
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Button:
        id: send_btn
        text: "Send"
        font_size: 36
        size: 100, 50
        background_color: 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1
        on_press: root.send_message()
        disabled: True
```

**errors and warning i got running buildozer **

```
you know my code and this is my errors using buildozer please modify my code
here is ass errors and warning that may help you
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
WARNING:Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
[WARNING]: prerequisites.py is experimental and does not support all prerequisites yet.
SyntaxError: unknown encoding: uft-8

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/bad_coding2.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/bad_coding2.py", line 0
SyntaxError: encoding problem: utf8 with BOM

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/bad_getattr.py'...
Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/bad_getattr2.py'...
Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/bad_getattr3.py'...
Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_3131.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_3131.py", line 2
    € = 2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character '€' (U+20AC)

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future10.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future10.py", line 3
    from __future__ import print_function
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future3.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future3.py", line 3
    from __future__ import rested_snopes
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature rested_snopes is not defined

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future4.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future4.py", line 3
    from __future__ import nested_scopes
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future5.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future5.py", line 4
    from __future__ import nested_scopes
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future6.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future6.py", line 3
    from __future__ import nested_scopes
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future7.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future7.py", line 3
    from __future__ import nested_scopes; import string; from __future__ import \
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future8.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future8.py", line 3
    from __future__ import *
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature * is not defined

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future9.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_future9.py", line 3
    from __future__ import nested_scopes, braces
    ^
SyntaxError: not a chance

Compiling '/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_pep3120.py'...
***   File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/test/badsyntax_pep3120.py", line 1
    print("b�se")
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: invalid start byte

SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

i am new in coding and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to handle runtime permissions for internet access. Here is the relevant info from [python-for-android](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions):

Runtime permissions

With API level >= 21, you will need to request runtime permissions to access the SD card, the camera, and other things.

This can be done through the android module which is available per default unless you blacklist it. Use it in your app like this:

> from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
> request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

The available permissions are listed here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Comment: thanks but it didn't help